# SVG Marker not displaying

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to make an SVG line with a little triangle in one end of it, using markers. This code, however, doesn't work. The marker doesn't show up. It's the first time I'm experimenting with svg, but the code doesn't seem to have any mistake... Is something wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

```
<svg id="rep-svg-13" class="rep-svg" style="position: absolute; left: -82px; top: -269px; display: block; opacity: 1;" width="35.6534886317" height="87.101405277" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<defs>

<marker id="myMarker-13" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3" orient="auto">
<polygon points="0,0 10,5 0,10" style="fill:rgb(100, 100, 100);"></polygon>
</marker>

</defs>

<line id="rep-arrow-13" x1="5.20716619357648" y1="-10.545316845143645" x2="30.44632243812352" y2="97.64672212214364" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="7" marker-end="url(#myMarker-13)"></line>

</svg>
```

Comment: You are probably printing it outside the visible area. See: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/5jPG3/

Answer (score 1):

Your line and arrow are there. They just aren't visible. Your position coordinates are drawing it off the screen:

```
left: -82px; top: -269px;
```

See this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/5jPG3/)**.

I replace the `left` and `top` values with positive values, changed the SVG's size and added a border to expose its the limits, and now you can see the arrow.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain the whole situation... The svg element is inside other elements, so, it's actually visible. The problem is that the code I pasted here works well on JSFiddle. However, all these elements are being created with javascript when you click a button. Apparently, the code works fine when pasted on JSFiddle. But in the actual page, generated by javascript, it doesn't work! Does this even make sense?

Comment: Can you edit your question in order to update it with that information (the JavaScript code that is not working)? It would be also useful if you could provide a fiddle with it.

Comment: Well, I had to "adapt" the code, but the essential was left in the Fiddle. Te problem is: the marker doesn't show, and it was supposed to. Can you tell me what's wrong? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/miguelrego/7HTmv/1/

Comment: you have an error in the path of the marker : "0,0 10,5 0,10" in first point has only one zero.